# Dec 11- 15 2015 Bar Hatorah conference, canvassing questions from others

Tags: discussion, question-catalog

I'll be attending [this conference on Torah and Science](http://www.torahscienceconference.org/) in about two weeks.

The topic space in 2015 is “Heart, Mind, Behavior and Purpose”:

> Conversations between Torah Wisdom and Scientific Knowledge about the
>   Universe, Human Life, and the Mind.

I was wondering how to make judaism SE viewers aware of this conference so that I could canvass questions pertaining to the topic space, run them by the various experts there and circle them back to Judaism SE.

Comment: *Most* of the topics and presenters seem to be medicine-related. You may wish to pick out some questions from [this list](//judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psych-mentalhealth+or+health-safety-shmira+or+medicine?sort=unanswered).

Comment: That list is excellent - thanks a bundle, I can work with that.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering how to make judaism SE viewers aware of this conference so that I could canvass questions

Post a question here on Meta explaining what the conference is (or linking to an explanation), announcing your attendance at it, and explicitly canvassing questions, i.e. asking people to post (lists of) links to relevant questions as answers to the Meta question.

You may also wish to post a reminder in [Bam](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/vdibarta-bam) once in a while.

Comment: For anyone wondering why I posted this on Dec. 15th, after it was (pretty much) no longer relevant to the asker: I originally posted something like this as a comment (now deleted) on the question, hoping that people would treat the question here as canvassing and post answers here that list [main] questions. But no one has as of today. So I instead decided to treat the question above literally, viz as asking how to make Yodeyans aware of the conference for future canvassing, and posted this answer, which is relevant also to future such conferences.